# Compute $\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{n} \right)-\sqrt{3}\right)$ without using L' Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{n} \right)-\sqrt{3}\right)$$ without using L'Hospital's rule.

By using L'Hospital's rule and

$$\tan'(  \Diamond  )=( \Diamond )'(1+\tan^{2}( \Diamond ))$$
I mean by  $\Diamond $ a function
so I got 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\left(\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)-\sqrt{3}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{\left(\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)-\sqrt{3}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{n}}\\
&=1+\tan^{2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)=1+\sqrt{3}^{2}=1+3=4
\end{align}

I'm interested in more ways of computing limit for this sequence.

Comment: $\tan \pi/3=\sqrt3$.

Comment: Could use the Taylor series: $\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{3} + x \right) = \sqrt{3} + 4x + O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 8):

The expression is a derivative. Since $\sqrt{3} = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$, the limit is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left( \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{1}{n} \right) - \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)$$

That is by the substitution $h = \frac{1}{n}$, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + h \right) - \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{3} \right)\right)$$

That is, $$\tan'(\pi/3)$$

Comment: this is nice i didn't notice that

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 1n\right)-\sqrt 3\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{\sqrt 3+\tan\frac 1n}{1-\sqrt 3\tan\frac 1n}-\sqrt 3\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n\tan\frac 1n}{1-\sqrt 3\tan\frac 1n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4\tan\frac 1n/(1/n)}{1-\sqrt 3\tan\frac 1n}\\&=\frac{4\cdot 1}{1-0}\end{align}$$

Comment: that's good work

Answer (score 1):

Taylor expansion would be a good idea. Around $x=0$ $$\tan(a+x)=\tan (a)+x \left(\tan ^2(a)+1\right)+x^2 \left(\tan ^3(a)+\tan
   (a)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac 1n$ and get $$\tan(a+\frac 1n)-\tan (a)=\left(\tan ^2(a)+1\right)\frac 1n+\cdots$$

Comment: could you give more details please

Comment: The expression you are working is  $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3} \right)$

Comment: $$\tan(a+\frac 1n)-\tan (a)=\left(\tan ^2(a)+1\right)\frac 1n+\cdots$$                             $$\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3} \right)=\left(\tan ^2(\dfrac{\pi}{3})+1\right)\frac 1n+\cdots$$   $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3} \right)=\left(\tan ^2(\dfrac{\pi}{3})+1\right)$$

Comment: What else did I mean ?

Comment: is there any difference if i use small o instead of big O

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sqrt 3\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sqrt 3}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{\tan\frac{\pi}{3}+\tan \frac{1}{n}}{1-\tan \frac{\pi}{3}\tan \frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt 3}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt 3+\tan \frac{1}{n}}{1-\sqrt 3\tan \frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt 3}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4\tan\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}(1-\sqrt 3\tan\frac{1}{n})}$$
$$=4\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\tan\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\times \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1-\sqrt 3\tan \frac{1}{n}}$$
$$=4(1)\left(\frac{1}{1-0}\right)=\color{red}{4}$$

Comment: your main idea is  $$\tan(x+y)=\dfrac{(tan(x)+tan(y))}{(1-tan(x)\cdot\tan(y))}\quad \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\tan}{x}=1$$

Comment: yes, you are right. this trig formula helps separating limits

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 1n\right)-\tan\frac{\pi}{3} \right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 1n-\frac{\pi}{3})\Big(1+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 1n)\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\Big) \right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\sin\frac 1n}{\cos \frac 1n}\times \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 1n)\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\Big)\\
&=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\frac 1n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos \frac 1n}\times \Big(1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 1n)\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\Big)\\
&=\frac{1}{1}\times(1+\sqrt 3\sqrt 3)\\
&=4
\end{align}

Comment: your main idea $$\tan(x+y)=\dfrac{(tan(x)+tan(y))}{(1-tan(x)\cdot\tan(y))}$$ with $x=\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $y=-\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\cos(x)}{x}=1$$

Comment: thanks for adding details :-)

Comment: ... and the end of your comment we need $\lim_{x\to0}\cos x =1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's very tempting to use L'Hopital's rule, indeed. An alternative proof may be like this: we construct approximations to the function $f (n) = \tan (\pi/3 + 1/n)$. For example, Taylor Series Approximation gives $$\tan \left (\frac {\pi} {3} + \frac {1} {n} \right) = \tan \frac {\pi} {3} + \frac {4} {n} + o \left (\frac {1} {n}\right).$$ Putting this back in the limit we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(\tan \left(\frac {\pi} {3} + \frac {1} {n} \right) - \sqrt{3} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (4 + o (1)) = 4.$$